# Windows 10 failure to compile with Node and React - syntax errors?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, syntax-error

I've been trying to start up a React project but can't avoid the following syntax error message. I've tried Yarn only to run into more errors (that would be for another post). My coworkers have no trouble running this on their Macs, so I'm wondering if it's a Windows specific issue? Totally lost on this one:

```
./src/ducks/auth/index.js
Syntax error: C:/Users/user/code/project/src/ducks/auth/index.js: Unexpected 
token, expected ; (5:20)

  3 | export * from './constants';
  4 | 
> 5 | export default from './reducer';
    |                     ^
  6 | 
  7 | export * from './selectors';
```

Comment: Please include more information about your build system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you `importing` or `exporting`? Your syntax looks half and half right now. If you are exporting:

```
export default <name of function>
```

if you are importing:

```
import <name of default function> from './reducer
```

edit: Now that I look at it, you're obviously importing. When importing, you have to state the exact name of what you exported. There is no keyword `default` when importing. Also, you need to use `import`, not `export`.

Comment: I ended up doing a work-around using yarn and didn't have an issue with the syntax.